# XAMPP localhost - Access denied error 403 after changing directory

Tags: php, apache, xampp, webserver, phpstorm

I'm using php storm for a project and I tried to change from the built in web server to the apache one as it messed with my url redirections.

Using a mac, I changed the directory to this one :

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/x/Desktop/CMS"
<Directory "/Users/x/Desktop/CMS">
```

After restarting the server, typing localhost in the search bar should direct me to the index.php file but I get :

**error 403 access denied**
[image]

This is the project structure :

[image]

I also configured the xampp server in the deployment like this :
[image]

The error log for the apache server give me these, so I tried reading on modifying permissions using sudo and chmod but I honestly dont know what i'm doing.

```
[Tue Jan 25 12:00:45.361077 2022] [core:error] [pid 4447] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:49579] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/Users/x/Desktop') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Tue Jan 25 12:00:45.430624 2022] [core:error] [pid 4447] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:49579] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/Users/x/Desktop') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://localhost/
[Tue Jan 25 12:00:45.527855 2022] [core:error] [pid 4447] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:49579] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/Users/x/Desktop') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Tue Jan 25 12:00:45.580902 2022] [core:error] [pid 4447] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:49579] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/Users/x/Desktop') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://localhost/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not advise serving from Users folder. Create a new folder in the root of your C drive and serve from there. Also make sure that you have access permissions granted.

```
DocumentRoot "/folder_one/folder_two"


<Directory "/folder_one/folder_two">

    Require all granted

</Directory>
```

Comment: I fixed it before you answered, moving the project into the User folder instead of the Desktop. I also did change the user to my **username** in the apache config file and it works now. Is there any reason that apache would not have access to Users/username/Desktop but Users/username it does ?

Comment: it's never a good idea to serve from users folders on windows or linux, those folders have special permissions, that why it is best to serve from a folder on the root of the drive.

Comment: Alright, thank you  !